# Flutter Horizontal ListView with Two or More Lines with infinite Scroll

Tags: listview, flutter

I´ve tried several times but it seems that the ListView.Builder with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, **only has space for one Line.**

Is is possible to make it into two or more Lines?

[image]

Comment: Yes, `ListView` would only have one line. You'll have to divide your elements in 2 list and use two `ListView`, however I'd suggest you to use `Wrap`.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to create this horizontal multiline list??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this plugin: [Flutter Staggered Grid View](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

In your case you could make something like this but horizontally:

[image: Flutter StaggeredGridView]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the vertical wrap widget inside a horizontal SingleChildScrollView widget but don't forget to surround the entire thing with a Container with a small width
try this :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6LR1.png)

```
Widget buildCatigoriesList(List catigoryList) {

return Container(
  height: 100,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Wrap(
      spacing: -1,
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: catigoryList
          .map((element) => Container(
              // margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
              width: 130,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: AutoSizeText(
                element.title,
                maxFontSize: 12,
                minFontSize: 10,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )))
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to split  your component and add a second listview